# Link formatting issue when clicking '5 new answers' banner

Tags: bug

I left a tab open on a question on MSO. When I came back it said that '5 New Answers' were available for me. I clicked the banner to load them up and found that *all* of them had the following formatting issue:

[image]

None of the other answers that were loaded when I first arrived at this page has the issue. I wanted to check it again to be sure but I'll have to wait around for an answer on a page I've already got open so it's not the easiest to test.

Comment: There's an unusual gap at my side. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwHNU.png Firefox 69, Ubuntu on [movies.se].

Comment: Yep, the layout for that section of a post changed very recently. I don't see a problem with it on my end though. When it happens, maybe Inspect the element and check out the `.lsep` separator? It's *supposed* to result in 6px between each button (plus 8px for the padding on the `<a>`s), which it does properly on my screen no matter the window layouts I tried

Comment: Just to make sure, you aren't running any custom styles or userscripts when this problem comes up, right?

Comment: Nope - blank browser with no other extensions of userscripts. @CertainPerformance

Comment: I *think* they reverted whatever changes they made, I'm betting you can't reproduce this anymore?