# Alignment issue in post-menu hyperlinks

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, user-experience

Please see this below image that `flag` menu/button alignment is little bit right  while compare with `share` menu/button.

Screen Shot:

> [image]

You can check by clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388893/what-is-the-difference-between-ngfor-and-ngforof-in-angular2).

Comment: It gets a lot worse with userscripts. Text is broken up, and multiple links now pushes the "edited" box over the box for OP. Something is definitely broken

Comment: A similar issue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390021/

Comment: Hi guy's. Is this bug will be resolved or not?

Comment: Hope this issue has been fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I *think* they reverted whatever changes they made